# How to preserve attributes in xsl:variable body?

Tags: xslt-1.0, xpath-1.0

data

```
<mydoc>
    <setting>foo</setting>
    <foo sound="aaaa"/>
    <bar sound="brrr"/>
    <cat sound="meow"/>
</mydoc>
```

if no conditional logic is needed,

```
<xsl:variable name="result1" select="/mydoc/foo"/>
```

works fine.

but if I need conditional logic,

```
<xsl:variable name="result2">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="/setting='foo'">
            <!-- what to put here -->
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="/setting='cat'">
            <!-- what to put here -->
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <!-- what to put here -->
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

desired output:

- when setting = `'foo'`, result = `<foo sound="aaa"/>` (the whole element complete with attribute)
- when setting = `'cat'`, result = `<cat sound="meow"/>` (the whole element complete with attribute)
- otherwise, result = `<bar sound="brrr"/>` (the whole element complete with attribute)

How do I get the `result2` variable to be an element with attributes, as it does in `result1`? I want to use $result2/sound, and some other elements / attributes of $result2 and / or it's children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```xml
<xsl:variable name="result2" select="/mydoc[setting='foo']/foo |
                                     /mydoc[setting='cat']/cat |
                                     /mydoc[not(setting='foo' or setting='cat')]/bar"/>
```

Because of the conditions in square brackets exactly one member of the union will effectively be selected.

If you put something inside the `<xsl:variable>` element rather than use `select`, your variable will contain a result tree fragment, not a nodeset.

Comment: I have edited my question to make the logic more convoluted, such that something more than `not`  is required. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on using `xsl:choose` (why?) then the only option open to you is to use `xsl:copy`. However, this has some side effects:

1. This will create a copy of the selected node/s and make it a child of the variable; in effect, it will create a separate document and the copied nodes will no longer be descendants of the XML input's root;
2. The variable will be a *result-tree-fragment* and you won't be able to process it in any way unless you convert it to a *node-set* first. Here, "process" includes accessing individual nodes inside the variable.

The following example demonstrates this:

**XML**

```
<mydoc>
    <setting>foo</setting>
    <foo bar="a"/>
    <bar foo="b"/>
</mydoc>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
exclude-result-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/mydoc">
    <xsl:variable name="temp">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="setting='foo'">
                <xsl:copy-of select="foo"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy-of select="bar"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
    <output>
        <xsl:value-of select="exsl:node-set($temp)/foo/@bar" />
    </output>   
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>a</output>
```

Do note that if you change:

```
<xsl:value-of select="exsl:node-set($temp)/foo/@bar" />
```

to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$temp/foo/@bar" />
```

you will get an error.